# How to handle mousedown in lit

Tags: typescript, lit

I have the a list of thumbnails that are rendered to the screen as follows:

```
  <div
         class="color"
         style="background:${rgbToHex(color.value.r, color.value.g, color.value.b )}"
  >
      <context-menu></context-menu>
  </div>
```

When I hold on the color div, I want to show the context menu. Only on hold not hover. How can I do that using lit and typescript? Please note its more than one thumbnail that's rendered. So I need to show the context menu for the thumbnail that the person holds on.

Comment: count the seconds the cursor is stationary over an item after a ``mouseenter`` event , there is no default event

Comment: Hi @Danny'365CSI'Engelman can you show me example code? I’m so confused. Would really help. Thanks

Comment: I don't do Lit, I stick to native Web Components

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in lit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the menu on `mousedown` event and hide it on either `mouseup` or `mouseleave`.

Lit has syntax for declaratively adding event listeners so you can do something like the following assuming you have methods on your element class to handle showing/hiding the menu.

```
html`
  <div
    @mousedown=${this.showMenu}
    @mouseup=${this.hideMenu}
    @mouseleave=${this.hideMenu}
    class="color"
    style="background:${rgbToHex(color.value.r, color.value.g, color.value.b )}"
  >
      <context-menu></context-menu>
  </div>`;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a non-Lit version

```html
<script>
  customElements.define('hover-stationary', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      const createElement = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
      let timeoutId;
      super().attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).append(
        createElement("style", { innerHTML: `:host { display: inline-block }` }),
        createElement("slot", {}),
      );
      this.onmouseenter = (e) => {
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => this.show(), 2000);
      }
      this.onmouseleave = (e) => {
        this.hide();
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      }
    }
    show(){ this.style.background = "green"   }
    hide(){ this.style.background = "initial" }
  });
</script>
<hover-stationary title="Hover over me for 2 seconds">Hover target #1</hover-stationary>
<hover-stationary title="Hover over me for 2 seconds">Hover target #2</hover-stationary>
```